# NumPy Array Conversion

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new to python and I'm trying to convert a (m,n,1) multidimensional array to (m,n) in a fast way, how can I go about it?

Also given a (m,n,k) array how can I split it to k (m,n) arrays? (each of the k members belongs to a different array)

Comment: when you say "array" (the input one) what do you mean? can you show a code example

Comment: Why do you need to do the latter? What have you tried? This is pretty basic stuff, so can you at least show what documentation you have looked at?

Comment: It would help if you gave some toy data and an example of what you already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reshape a NumPy Array `arr` with shape (m, n, 1) to the shape (m, n) simply use:

```
arr = arr.reshape(m, n)
```

You can get a list of (m, n)-shaped arrays out of a (m, n, k) shaped array `arr_k` by:

```
array_list = [arr_k[:, :, i] for i in range(arr_k.shape[2])]
```

Answer (score 3):

To reshape array a you can use `a.reshape(m,n).`

To split array a along the depth dimension, you can use `numpy.dsplit(a, a.shape[2])`.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dsplit.html#numpy.dsplit

Comment: I like using dsplit, however the returned list will contain arrays of shape (m, n, 1)